# Compiling C++ AMP using qmake fails

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qmake, c++-amp

I have the following main.cpp file:

```
#include <amp.h>
using namespace concurrency;
int main()
{
  int arr[] = {42};
  array_view<int, 1> v(1, arr);
  return 0;
}
```

and a .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -EHsc
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

If I compile main.cpp from the Visual Studio 2012 command line (just using cl /EHsc main.cpp), everything works fine. But if I use qmake and nmake there is alway a link error, that there are unresolved external symbols (coming from amp). Does anybody know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out, what the problem is: In the mkspec file qmake.conf the compiler flag `Zc:wchar_t-` causes the compiler to translate some types relatet to `wchar_t` incorrectly and hence the resulting symbols could not be resolved.

To solve this problem, change the above .pro file to

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -EHsc -Zc:wchar_t
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

(add -Zc:wchar_t to QMAKE_CXXFLAGS).

Comment: You should make your answer as the answer so they it doesn't show up in the unanswered questions list. Cheers.

Comment: Hey, I' ve got a similar problem (qt, MSVC++) but I am using MSVC++ compiler (not qmake). Where should I put this modifier?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add

```
LIBS += -lname_of_the_amp_lib
```

Sorry but I don't know the name of the lib...

Comment: The compiler itself takes care to link against the required import libs.